# Cross Browser compatibility issues - Firefox vs. Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

I'm having trouble debugging a cross browser compatibility issue. Specifically the issue is in Firefox where the slider isn't showing up in the proper place, it looks ok in Chrome and Safari.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

The url is`http://74.52.120.208/~doucce/`

Comment: Please ask a specific questions, not "it doesn't work, how do I fix it?" Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Also, pasting a link to a raw IP address URI is a bit scary. Please post sample code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your global.css line 405 and remove following line

```
#home-slider .entry-content {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This will work for sure .Check this out

Comment: Thanks, I removed it but I don't think that fixed it in firefox.

Comment: i was check it in firefox.let me know if get any success ?

Comment: aha i had to flush the cache. Thanks!

Comment: hey thanks again for your help earlier. The problem is still present on Mac Firefox browsers. any ideas what would be causing that?

Comment: i'll let you know after checking your site from it .